# python: assign and read out the values of a 2-d list

Tags: python

Here is a snippet of python code:

```
a = [[0]*3]*4
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(3):
        a[i][j] = i+j
        print(a[i][j])
print(a)
```

However, the outputs of the two prints are different.

The former one prints what I want. And the second prints all the same for the 4 sublists.

It seems the problem of shallow copying. I really don't understand how and why it happens.

**Update:**

After I have solved this, I found another problem:

```
a = [[0]*3]*4
for i in range(4):
    a[i] = [i, 2*i, 3*i]
```

The result is also what I want. I'm once again confused about this.

Who can tell me the difference?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The multiplier of operator taking a list and an int will make makes shallow copies of the elements of the list, so you're on the right track.

Initialise like this instead

```
a = [[0] * 3 for _ in range(4)]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have figured out why it happens from a previous question. Your answer is right, however, I don't know why the displayed post score is minus.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [[0]*3]*4
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(3):
        a[i][j] = i+j
        print(a)
        print(a[i][j])//show the execution at every step
print(a)
```

At each step the list with same column is updated with the same value.
output is

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
0
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
1
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
2
[[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]]
1
[[1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2]]
2
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
3
[[2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3]]
2
[[2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3]]
3
[[2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
4
[[3, 3, 4], [3, 3, 4], [3, 3, 4], [3, 3, 4]]
3
[[3, 4, 4], [3, 4, 4], [3, 4, 4], [3, 4, 4]]
4
[[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
5
[[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: The reason is that "* 4" just makes 3 references to the existing sublist [[0]*3] instead of making new sublists. Therefore, essentially it only creates only 1 sublist here.